# What adapter should I use to connect a hose to a sprayer?

Tags: watering, equipment

[image]

I got a 3/4 MIP to 3/4 MIP adapter to connect my sprayer to the hose. The size seems correct, but it's leaking water after they're connected. Do I have the wrong fitting?

Comment: Why are you connecting the sprayer to the female end of the hose?

Comment: I'm guessing because someone replaced the hose end (note that it's a clamp-on type) without realizing that both male and female replacements exist. My advice would be to remove that fitting and install the expected male version; problem solved, no M/M adapter needed.

Comment: @JACK both ends are female

Comment: In that case, yeah, someone e attached the wrong replacement fitting (for most expected uses), so you either need the double male fitting or a male replacement for that female, whichever is easier for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fitting you have there has tapered threads. They will not work in a garden hose or attachments. You'll need a 3/4 in. MHT Brass Coupling Fitting similar to the one shown below from Home Depot.

[image]

Comment: JD74's answer stated that it's MGT (Male Garden Hose). Which one is it, MGH or MHT?

Comment: @jeffrey  They are the same. MGH stands for male garden hose and MHT stands for male hose thread. They are just different acronyms for the samr thing

Comment: Likely less expensive to replace the *incorrect female* replacement clamp-on hose end with a *male* replacement clamp-on hose end, though. Brass fittings ain't cheap.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thank you Ecnerwal, can you link me to a youtube video on how to do that? I'm just beginning to learn this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Garden hoses are a different thread.  You need 3/4 MGH (Male Garden Hose).

Something like this will work.
[https://www.amazon.com/REGNHLIF-Garden-Adapter-Double-Connector/dp/B08CBHDVGD/ref=asc_df_B08CBHDVGD/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=461109272590&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=706857104561565318&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9019498&hvtargid=pla-975096161722&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08CBHDVGD)

Comment: Jack's answer stated that it's MHT (Male House Thread). Which one is it, MGH or MHT?